# Line in margin of page alongside some content

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to mark some parts of my document by addign a wide line in the margin, ideally in a fashion like this:

```
preceeding text

\begin{sideLine}
  Text
  \begin{float}
  \end{float}
  more text
\end{sideLine}
```

I tried with `tcolorbox`, however it does not play nice with floats. If I try to pack it inside the float, there are gaps in the line. I am not to bound on the idea of having a line next to the figure, but I do not like the gaps resulting from breaking and continuing the enviornment to avoid lost floats.
How do I get rid of the Gaps, is there a way to make the enviornment accept floats? (I guess I could limit them with `\floatBarrier` from `placeins` to be placed within the enviornments frame inside the document).

[image: notice the gap in the line next to the text]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\newtcolorbox{highlightTheoretical}[1][]{blanker, breakable, 
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    if odd page or oneside*={borderline west={3pt}{-25pt}{black}}{borderline east={3pt}{-25pt}{black}},
    before upper=\indent, parbox=false, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{highlightTheoretical}
lipsum
\end{highlightTheoretical}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{highlightTheoretical}
        \ffigbox{
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{imagefile}
    \caption{test}}{}
    \end{highlightTheoretical}
\end{figure}

\begin{highlightTheoretical}
    lipsum
\end{highlightTheoretical}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: I do use floatrow and intend to keep it, while it does not make a difference now it was not making a line besides the caption when `\ffigbox` was omitted, and there could be further complications.

Comment: Try to boxing a float is like try to catch the wind with a butterfly net. The floats float, it's their nature. You cannot/should not enclose a float in any type of box. But there are no problem to have any type of box/boxes inside a float. And there are no problem to use images inside a tcolorbox, where I suppose what `\captionof` will work also. So, where is the problem?

Comment: @Fran The problem is that I do like my automation, i.e. let latex figure out where the figure fits best on a page. While the example above is very short, in practice I have a few cases where I have 5 pages, across which I want to add the sideline (thus there is room for automatic float placement), yet I want to keep the float inside the lined "area" (i.e. so close that the side line does not get interrupted between the float and the text).

As tcolorbox provides an enviornment that does allow for page brakes, `box` might propably be a "wrong" term.

Answer (score 1):

As `Fran` commented, `floats` are special environments which you have to be careful with them. But you can still include captioned-non-floating figures with `capt-of` or `ccaption` packages. This figures will be inside the `tcolorbox` where you place them and the side line will be continous alogn the whole set. Following there is and example with `capt-of` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newtcolorbox{highlightTheoretical}[1][]{blanker, breakable, 
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
    if odd page or oneside*={borderline west={3pt}{-25pt}{black}}{borderline east={3pt}{-25pt}{black}},
    before upper=\indent, parbox=false, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{highlightTheoretical}
lipsum
 {\par\centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{imagefile}
    \captionof{figure}{test}
    \par
    }
    lipsum
\end{highlightTheoretical}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please see my lengthy comment under the question why I would like to keep floating pictures inside the `tcolorbox` (multipage enviornment)

Comment: @ted What you want is not possible. A `tcolorbox` can be a `floating` object, but it doesn't accept floating objects inside. The only solution I can think is declaring boxes for text and boxes for floats and once you know the final place, join the lines with an external `tikz` command.

Comment: Fair enough, +1 then. I am not 100% convinced there is no way in tex, but maybe there is no sane way.